# filteredArrayUsingPredicate to fill an array using mutable array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a runtime error that is happening at this line of code:

```
_searchresults = [_beerNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

serchresuls is a NSArray (nil objects)
beerNames is a NSArray M (196 objects)
and result predicate is a NScomparison predicate and I don't really understand what that means
Here is my code for the result predicate

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
```

and searchText is a NSCF string, but it only fills up with one letter before the program crashes.

The error it is giving me is this:

NSCFString 0x8cbce80> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: What is your predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predicate would work if `_beerNames` is an array containing objects that have a "name" property. But you have an array of strings, therefore the predicate should be

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText]
```

(with "self" instead of "name").

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote a simple example for you:
    Person *a = [Person new];
    a.name = @"a";
    a.number = @"200";
    a.age = 31;

```
Person *b = [Person new];
b.name = @"b";
b.number = @"300";
b.age = 21;

Person *c = [Person new];
c.name = @"c";
c.number = @"100";
c.age = 11;

NSArray *arr = @[a,b,c];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name like[cd] %@) AND (age > %i)",@"b", 10];
arr  = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Play with it.
For the predicates' syntax you can take a look here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB

in my example, for instance, the cd means it's case- and diacritic-insensitive like.”